# Ogg audio served from PHP-file unseekable on Chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, audio, http-headers

I'm developing a basic audio player using HTML5 audio element. All served files are .ogg coming from another system as a binary string through an API and printed out by a simple PHP handler (which includes some basic security checking) and there's really nothing I can do about it.

However, while everything works nicely on Firefox, Chrome has some issues regarding seeking, skipping or replaying (simply put: it can't be done). Getting audio duration from the audio element returns Infinity, and while currentTime returns correct value, it can't be manipulated.

I started fiddling with headers and response codes and nothing seems to work properly. Using response code 206 for partial content or declaring Accept-Ranges in header causes audio element to go disabled as it does when the source file doesn't exist.

Searching for proper headers didn't yield much results, since it always was about partial content and X-Content-Duration (which is a PITA to calculate because of VBR), which did absolutely nothing on Chrome.

Here are the relevant headers which work just fine on FF. Did I make a major mistake on something, or is there just some issue with Chrome?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK (changing this to 206 makes the file unplayable in Chrome)
Cache-Control: public, no-store
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="redacted.ogg"
Content-Length: 123456
X-Content-Duration: 12 (this does nothing on Chrome, works on FF)
Content-Range: bytes 0-123455/123456
Accept-Ranges: bytes (...as does including this)
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: audio/ogg
Expires: 0
Pragma: public
```

**Edit:** some kind of behaviour on Opera, probably on all Webkit browsers. Also doesn't work in `fread`/`file_get_contents` type of situations.

Comment: Also found this but with no answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928945/google-chrome-not-completing-request-if-a-partial-content-header-is-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, dumb me, it really was due the partial content. Chrome didn't really like the idea of taking the whole file at once (and caching it like FF), so to enable seeking and whatnot it needed Accept-Ranges: bytes, a bit of incoming header parsing to get the requested byte range and couple of lines which return that aforementioned byte range with correct partial content status (206), not just "bytes 0-(filesize-1)/filesize" (whole file), even if the first request asks for it (bytes=0-).

Hope this helps someone else as well.